# Spring MVC - Multipart form data

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I got this jsp file :

```
<form:form class="main-section" modelAttribute="demandeForm" commandName="demandeForm" 
name="demandeForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8" action="/validate.do?valider=valider">

<!-- Some input text -->

<ul>
   <li>
      <input type="file" name="file" >
   </li>
   <li>
      <input type="file" name="file" >
   </li>
   <li>
      <input type="file" name="file" >
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my form class :

```
public class DemandeForm {

    private MultipartFile[] file;

    public MultipartFile[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(final MultipartFile[] pFile) {
        this.file = pFile;
    }
}
```

And my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "valider")
public String valider(@Valid final DemandeForm pForm, final BindingResult pResult, final Model pModel, final HttpServletRequest pRequest) {

    // do things

    if (pResult.hasErrors()) {
        return MY_VUE;
    }

    // do things

}
```

`pResult`has binding error, and here is the error :

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String[] 
to required type org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile[] 
for property file; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type 
[org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property file[0]: 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

The error has appeared since I've added `charse=UTF-8` on the enctype value. I need this because I have files this accents and UTF-8 characters.

How can I deal with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="defaultEncoding"><value>utf-8</value></property>
</bean>
```

And don't use:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8"
```

in your form

Answer (score 0):

you can set controller parameter as

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
```

then you can get file name,size,etc... like

```
file.getOriginalFilename()
```